Running google chrome inside Docker container on MacOS in GUI
I am using MacOS with Apple Silicon M1 Pro chip.
I want to run Chrome browser for Linux using Docker in GUI mode.
This is my Dockerfile
# Use the official Ubuntu base image
FROM ubuntu:24.04

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    gnupg \
    software-properties-common \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libgbm1 \
    libasound2 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libcups2 \
    libdrm2 \
    libnspr4 \
    libnss3 \
    libxss1 \
    libxtst6 \
    fonts-liberation \
    xdg-utils \
    libu2f-udev \
    x11-apps \
    sudo \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add Google Chrome repository and install Google Chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create a normal user
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash chrome \
    && echo "chrome ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

# Switch to the normal user
USER chrome

# Set environment variables for X11 forwarding
ENV DISPLAY=:0
ENV XAUTHORITY=/home/chrome/.Xauthority

# Set the entrypoint to run Chrome
ENTRYPOINT [ "google-chrome" ]

Now I am trying to build Docker image
sudo docker build -t chrome-container .

That is giving me errors
[+] Building 6.8s (5/7)                                                                                                                                           docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.32kB                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:24.04                                                                                                                   2.9s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:24.04@sha256:2e863c44b718727c860746568e1d54afd13b2fa71b160f5cd9058fc436217b30                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [2/4] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     wget     gnupg     software-properties-common     libx11-xcb1     libxcomposite1     libxcursor1     libxdamage1     3.9s
------
 > [2/4] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     wget     gnupg     software-properties-common     libx11-xcb1     libxcomposite1     libxcursor1     libxdamage1     libxrandr2     libgbm1     libasound2     libatk1.0-0     libatk-bridge2.0-0     libcups2     libdrm2     libnspr4     libnss3     libxss1     libxtst6     fonts-liberation     xdg-utils     libu2f-udev     x11-apps     sudo     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
1.111 Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease [256 kB]
2.291 Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease
2.291   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
2.584 Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-updates InRelease [126 kB]
2.884 Err:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-updates InRelease
2.884   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
3.031 Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-backports InRelease [126 kB]
3.339 Err:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-backports InRelease
3.339   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
3.516 Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-security InRelease [126 kB]
3.842 Err:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-security InRelease
3.842   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
3.846 Reading package lists...
3.863 W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
3.863 E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease' is not signed.
3.863 W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
3.863 E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-updates InRelease' is not signed.
3.863 W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-backports InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
3.863 E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-backports InRelease' is not signed.
3.863 W: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
3.863 E: The repository 'http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-security InRelease' is not signed.
------
Dockerfile:5
--------------------
   4 |     # Install necessary packages
   5 | >>> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
   6 | >>>     wget \
   7 | >>>     gnupg \
   8 | >>>     software-properties-common \
   9 | >>>     libx11-xcb1 \
  10 | >>>     libxcomposite1 \
  11 | >>>     libxcursor1 \
  12 | >>>     libxdamage1 \
  13 | >>>     libxrandr2 \
  14 | >>>     libgbm1 \
  15 | >>>     libasound2 \
  16 | >>>     libatk1.0-0 \
  17 | >>>     libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
  18 | >>>     libcups2 \
  19 | >>>     libdrm2 \
  20 | >>>     libnspr4 \
  21 | >>>     libnss3 \
  22 | >>>     libxss1 \
  23 | >>>     libxtst6 \
  24 | >>>     fonts-liberation \
  25 | >>>     xdg-utils \
  26 | >>>     libu2f-udev \
  27 | >>>     x11-apps \
  28 | >>>     sudo \
  29 | >>>     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  30 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y     wget     gnupg     software-properties-common     libx11-xcb1     libxcomposite1     libxcursor1     libxdamage1     libxrandr2     libgbm1     libasound2     libatk1.0-0     libatk-bridge2.0-0     libcups2     libdrm2     libnspr4     libnss3     libxss1     libxtst6     fonts-liberation     xdg-utils     libu2f-udev     x11-apps     sudo     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/wh2rk22doe4prdqnrdd8uidwt

How can I make this working?

Why you need sudo for docker build ? Have you checked there is enough free disk storage ?

Just on the higher-level question, a Docker container is not a VM, and it's difficult to run interactive GUI applications like full Web browsers there.  What is your end goal with this setup?  Do you need a VM with a simulated display, or can you use the Web browser on the host system?

@Philippe: Yes there is sufficient space on disk.

@DavidMaze: End goal is to get chrome running on Linux on MacOs host. This should be possible by running xserver in container and enable X11 forwarding. In the host we can use XQuartz to connect to display.

Have you tried docker build without sudo ?

looks like others have gotten it to work using a debian base

@Philippe: without sudo i get permisson error

Try to fix this permisson error
